# how to write a query in hibernate to select a column

Tags: hibernate

I'm using hibernate template to retrieve a data from the table `course` which has two columns,
`courseId` and `courseName`. I want to select `courseName` from `course` using hibernate template.

When I use:

```
List<String> courseNames=hibernateTemplate.find("courseName from domain.Course");
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a full form of `select` query:

```
select c.courseName from domain.Course c
```

**See also:**

- [16.6. The select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)

Answer (score 1):

```
hibernateTemplate.find("c.courseName from domain.Course c")
```

Just a guess, based on JPQL syntax.