# Specifying a list of fields in HQL doesn't seem to work

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, oracle10g, hql

I have the following HQL in Hibernate using Spring MVC.

```
List<Colour>list=session.createQuery("from Colour order by colourId desc")
.setFirstResult((currentPage-1)*rowsPerPage)
.setMaxResults(rowsPerPage).list();
```

It works and returns a list of rows from the colour table (actually operates upon the Colour entity (POJO) that I can understand) in Oracle 10g.

What if I need to retrieve a list fields, I'm trying the following.

```
List<Colour>list=session.createQuery("colourId, colourName, colourHex from Colour order by colourId desc")
.setFirstResult((currentPage-1)*rowsPerPage)
.setMaxResults(rowsPerPage).list();
```

It ends with an excpetion

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

In some articles, it was mentioned that the following version of HQL should (or may) work

```
List<Colour>list=session.createQuery("select colourId, colourName, colourHex from Colour order by colourId desc")
.setFirstResult((currentPage-1)*rowsPerPage)
.setMaxResults(rowsPerPage).list();
```

but unfortunately, it also didn't work for me. Using the `createSQLQuery()` method to execute native SQL would work but I want to stick to the `createQuery()` method with HQL unless it's absolutely necessary. How can I specify a list of fields in HQL?

Comment: Try `List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery(your_hql).list();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with yorkw's comment. If you select properties in your query then you cannot ask for a `List<Colour>` object to be returned from a call to `.list()`.

Instead you should do this

```
    List<Object[]> rows = session.createQuery("select c.colourId, c.colourName, c.colourHex " +
        " from Colour c " + 
        " order by c.colourId desc").list();
```

Then iterate over the list object and instantiate your objects. Or whatever you need to do.

```
    for ( Object[] row : rows ) {
        Long colourId = (Long)row[0];
        // ... etc
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try creating a map? Something like this:

```
SELECT NEW MAP( colour.colourId AS id
              , colour.colourName AS name ...) 
  FROM Colour colour 
  ORDER BY colour.colourId
```

I use the alias for Colour "colour" so hibernate knows from which entity is the property I am referencing, I am implying all those properties are from the same entity, if not, then check your referencing!

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) specification, this query `select c.colourId, c.colourName, c.colourHex from Colour c order by c.colourId desc` should work but it doesn't. Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10996261) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5484814) questions and corresponding answers indicate the same thing. I don't understand the reason why it doesn't work in my case.